# Arduino WDT timer value after external interrupt

Tags: arduino

I am counting pulses using an external interrupt, but I put the processor to sleep in between pulses using wdt_enable, using the 8-second interval.

When the interrupt occurs and the processor wakes up to service the interrupt, is it possible to find out how long into the 8-second period I am? That is, can I read the wdt timer to see how long it has been running (or how long it has to go)?

Answer (score 0):

The ATMEL328p [Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) Page 51 shows the architecture of the Watchdog. There does not seem to be a method to read back the Watchdog Prescaler. The answer assumes you are using an Arduino with a 328p.